# How can I use in my script (.proj) the MSBuild Arguments set in my Build Definition

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I need to define some fixed version info in my Build Definition, so I thought about setting the MSBuild Arguments option with this version info. However, I don't know how can I get this arguments values in my MSBuild script.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get them the same way you get any other MSBuild arguments.  So for example if you set the Workflow Argument to:

MSBuild Arguments: /p:foo=99

From your MSBuild script you access it by doing $(foo)

Comment: What if I create an argument in the build process template, will it be available in the MSBuild script? I tried using $(processArgumentName) and it causes an error (not found).

Comment: The only arguments available in MSBuild are the ones that you explicitly pass into the MSBuild activity.

Comment: I'm trying to get the values of the arguments I've created to set them as MSBuildArguments, however they are not recognized in the Workflow editor.